# RS232 wire color

Tags: rs232

I have RS232 wire and want to take form it a ICSP end for my serial AVR programmer , I find it difficult to assign colors to pins ,so is ther any standards .

the color I found after cutting the end of cable are:white-yellow-red-orange-green-black-purple -brown-blue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RS232 (aka EIA232/TIA232) describes the electrical (voltage levels) and mechanical (connector type and pinout) aspect of the interface. Wire colors are not part of this, you can do with them whatever you want. Like David says, you can't even be sure that black is ground.

Answer (score 6):

There are no common standards for wire color with RS-232 cables.  Usually black is ground, but not always.  You'll just have to figure it out yourself.  Get a multimeter to figure out which wires connect to which pin on the connector.