# Is it possible to create a homemade programmer for PIC16F84A?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, usb, microprocessor, programmer

Is this simple circuit able to program a microcontroller? Or Does it need any other components?

After looking at [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37059/just-chopped-a-cable-is-red-power-black-ground), I can know where D+ and D- of USB cable are, by looking at the colours of wires.

After reading [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/35007C.pdf), I think that D+ and D- should be connected to pins 13 and 14. But I don't know which one I should connect to which. for eg. should I connect pin 13 to D+ or D-? If I connected them in a wrong way by mistake, Does that damage the microcontroller?

What is the best software to communicate with this circuit? I want windows to recognise or add this new hardware without getting in troubles.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftcrhW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit diagram in your question is nonsense. The PIC16F84A does not support USB, so connecting a USB cable to it won't do anything useful.

The connections you've come up with are *doubly* nonsense. Pin 14 of the PIC16F84A is VDD. Connecting D+ to VDD will tie it to your power supply. If you are using the 5V supply from the USB cable, this may damage the USB host device.

If you want to program a PIC part over USB, you need to buy a USB PIC programmer. This is not negotiable. You cannot build one out of a USB cable; it requires active components.

Comment: You can buy a PICkit3 for like $20

Answer (score 0):

It is two bucks worth of parts assuming you have a $10 USB to TTL virtual adapter.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tony. I'm a beginner and I don't understand these words stands for (DTR, CTS, RTS, PGD, PGC).

Comment: Also, a USB cable is always four wires. Why there's six wires in the USB COM?

Comment: Sorry I assumed everyone has a virtual COM with USB to serial port adapter as COM port which have been deleted on computers these days, yet so essential for projects like this.   https://www.google.ca/search?q=USB+virtual+com+port+module+or+cable+with+DTR%2C+CTS+and+RTS&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Fdu5WO-gI8uC8QeCu7bgBA#tbm=shop&q=USB+virtual+com+port+module+&*&spd=9280719118028653764

Comment: @MichaelGeorge, if you don't understand something, there is a modern tool called "internet", with a search engine called GOOGLE. Try it sometimes.

Comment: also http://www.8lots.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=11216&c=CAD&l=cae