# What do the different cables of the RS232 cable mean?

Tags: rs232

I learned that the TTL-232R-3V3 cable that I bought to program my MCU has 6 differently colored ports. What do each mean and do they represent specific things?
[image: my cable]

Comment: You bought the cable, so you know who is the manufacturer. Get the datasheet for the cable and read it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [RS232 wire color](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29915/rs232-wire-color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be one of those: http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables.htm

Most likely: http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_TTL-232R_CABLES.pdf [Page 10/11]